# Toilet tank fill tube

Tags: plumbing

None of my 3 toilet tanks have a fill tube leading to the overflow, and yet my bowl fills with water. Is the fill tube necessary, as this is how to toilets were when we bought from the builder

Answer (score 1):

Different toilets use different means to refill the bowl.